# Retrieve AD User's Entra ID from Microsoft Graph API using email address?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, microsoft-graph-api, graphserviceclient

I am trying to get the Entra Id of a user from their email address before adding them to a specific group using Microsoft Graph API via a .Net Web App.

In Azure Portal I have registered the application and generated a client secret to use the Client credentials Auth Flow. For API permissions I have been granted User.Read and User.Read.All on our company tenant.

I create my GraphServiceClient using the following code:

```
public MicrosoftGraphService(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

    var tenantId = configuration["MicrosoftGraph:TenantId"];
    var clientId = configuration["MicrosoftGraph:ClientId"];
    var clientSecret = configuration["MicrosoftGraph:Secret"];
    var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
    {
        AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
    };

    var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

    _graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
}
```

I call the Graph API by passing in the email address trying to retrieve the user object where I can read the Entra ID. I do this using the following code:

```
public async Task<GraphUser> GetUserAsync(string emailAddress)
{
    try
    {
        var foundUser = await _graphServiceClient.Users[emailAddress].GetAsync();
        var user = (new GraphUser()
        {
            UserId = foundUser.Id,
            DisplayName = foundUser.DisplayName,
            Email = emailAddress
        });

        return user;
    }
    catch
    {
        // Not found in AD
        return null;
    }
}
```

However, when it invokes the _graphServiceClient.Users[emailAddress].GetAsync() call I get an error stating: "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."

From the documentation I have read having the User.Read.All api permission granted for the application should be enough to get the data. What am I doing wrong?

[image: The permissions granted on the app registration]

Comment: Can you attach the screenshot of the API permissions granted to the Microsoft Entra application?

Comment: I've added the permissions granted.

Comment: Please check the answer below, you need to grant User.Read.All application type API permission as you are making use of client credential flow

Comment: @Rukmini, thank you. I see the error now. I have a delegated Read.User.All permission not an Application level permission. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error ***"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation"*** usually occurs if the Microsoft Entra ID application doesn't have required permissions to perform the action.

Initially I got the **same error**:

[image]

**To resolve the error,** make sure to grant **`User.Read.All`** **application type** API permission as you are making use of client credential flow.

- `User.Read.All` delegated type API permission must be granted when you make use of user interactive flow.

Grant the **`User.Read.All`** **application type** API permission like below:

[image]

***I am able to successfully retrieve the users with UPN like below:***

```cs
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
        var clientId = "ClientID";
        var tenantId = "TenantID";
        var clientSecret = "ClientSecret";

        var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
        {
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
        };

        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
            tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

        try
        {
            var result = await graphClient.Users["User@XXX.onmicrosoft.com"].GetAsync();
            Console.WriteLine($"User details: {result.DisplayName}, {result.Mail}, {result.Id}");
        }
            catch (ODataError odataError)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error?.Code);
            Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error?.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Get a user - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)